# How do I instantiate an Object that uses generics with Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, generics

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Dao<T>{
...
}
```

I want to do this:

```
new Dao<Student>();
```

from the Spring XML configuration.

Can that be done? How?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Reading up about [type erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) should help you understand this a bit better.

At runtime, the type parameters for a generic class are *erased*. Meaning, as cletus said, generics in Java are basically syntactic sugar - they are only a compile-time feature.

Since Spring is instantiate objects at run-time, it is actually free to instantiate a `Dao` of any type - and actually, there is nothing stopping it from creating a `Dao` and passing in `Student` types in some methods and `Teacher` types in another.

So basically the answer is, Spring has no idea that the `Dao` type is meant to be parameterized and can't do anything with it.

Answer (score 8):

You can't do it and the reason you can't do it is that it actually means nothing.  By that I mean that Java generics are syntactic sugar so what type you create a bean with is irrelevant.  You can inject it into anything taking a Dao (or Dao) just fine at which point it'll be using the implicit casting of whatever type it's been injected into.