# Spring 4 Feature : Autowired by generics is a little lie

Tags: java, generics, autowired, spring-4

Autowired by generics works perfectly fine with static type.But when i write

`@Autowired`

`private GenericDAO<T> dao;`

with dynamic type at runtime getting error at deploy time:"multiple bean definition found."

Does Autowired by type in Spring 4 not work with runtime type?.

Comment: No it won't and never will due to the nature of generics. So it isn't a lie it works if you specify the type it works while still being able to use a genericdao.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Problem with generic types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857149/spring-problem-with-generic-types)

Comment: Some what similar but in my case haven't extends that class. so no case of hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you expect spring to resolve it for a generic type. If there was only one bean eligible it would be easy for the Spring container to resolve and autowire it.

The Generics is a mechanism for developer type safety which is erased/not available in the run time.

```
@Autowired
private GenericDAO<T> dao;
```

and if config has

```
<bean id="genericDAO" class="com.example.GenericDAO" />
```

as only bean that satisfies the requirement, then both Spring and yourself can be happy of serving the purpose. By the way, none lied :)