# Define a concurrent hash set spring bean?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, web.xml

In Spring I can define a HashSet like so in XML:

```
<bean id="subscriberStore" class="java.util.HashSet"/>
```

And, I can do the following in the code to create a concurrent hash set:

```
subscriberStore = Collections.newSetFromMap(
                     new ConcurrentHashMap<Subscriber, Boolean>());
```

But is there any way I can do this in one step in the XML? E.g. something like:

```
 <bean id="subscriberStore" class="java.util.HashSet"/>
         <  Some code here to set subscriberStore to the result 
    of Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Subscriber, Boolean>?   >
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Bean configuration:

```
<!-- The bean to be created via the factory bean -->
<bean id="exampleBean"
      factory-bean="myFactoryBean"
      factory-method="createInstance"/>

<bean id="myFactoryBean" class="com.rory.ConcurrentHashMapFactory"/>
```

And the factory class:

```
public class ConcurrentHashMapFactory {
  public Set<Subscriber> createInstance() {
    Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Subscriber, Boolean>());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though shouldn't the createInstance return a Set rather than a Map?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following:

```
<bean
    id="subscriberStore"
    class="java.util.Collections"
    factory-method="newSetFromMap"
>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

However, if generic types are important to you, create a custom, static factory method (as [Boris Pavlović](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32090/boris-pavlovic) kind of suggests in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9976804/649852)).  You might want to take a look at [this SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560867/how-do-i-instantiate-an-object-that-uses-generics-with-spring-framework) for some information regarding generics and Spring XML bean definitions.